# Как записать в ларавел такой запрос?

Tags: laravel

есть запрос, на подсчет суммы покупок за последние 12 месяцев

```
SELECT SUM(`cost`),
DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%Y-%m') as period
FROM `payments`
WHERE `created_at` >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 11 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')
GROUP BY period
```

как записать в ларавел этот запрос?

Answer (score 0):

А чем состоит трудность?

[Доки по запросам к бд](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries).
1) Для суммы `DB::raw('SUM(cost)')` в вашем `SELECT`.
2) Для дат используйте [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), который идет с Laravel из коробки.
   - чтобы не писать постоянные вызовы к Carbon в коде, используйте [мутаторы в вашей модели](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators).
3) Если не хотите писать через DB::, используйте [Eloquent Orm](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent).